# Learning modern differential geometry before curves and surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, learning

What might one miss by learning modern differential geometry without first learning about curves and surfaces?

I'm currently reading this book on differential geometry which starts with manifolds and builds from there. I'm already deep inside it and it's a perfect fit for me.

Still, I wonder what i might have missed by skipping on learning the "classical" differential geometry. The book has a chapter about hypersurfaces but i'm still a bit worried that i might miss something important.

What are some important notions from classical differential geometry i better know?

Comment: The main thing you'll miss is intuition. It's very helpful to have those classical models in your mind, as they are inspiration for more general definitions and give you some useful examples.

Comment: @SimonS I haven't had any trouble with intuition yet and i am learning the examples as i go Other than that is their any major disadvantage?

Comment: That's a good question. Hope to see some good answers.

Comment: If you're comfortable with  geometry on manifolds, it costs nothing to take a look into curves and surfaces. How can you speak of the tangent space to a manifold without being able to work with tangents to curves, or tangent planes to surfaces? How do you compute the curvature of a curve, or the mean curvature of a surface at a point? These are basic questions you need to know from curves and surfaces...

Comment: @BeniBogosel So i guess my question comes down to: is it "safe" to learn it in such a way that these things come as exercises and/or special cases to the general theory rather than learning them beforehand.

Comment: I don't see why what you are doing could not be "safe". But it's just like talking about derivatives, without actually finding a derivative of a concrete function like $\exp,\sin,\ln$. Differential geometry was not a success for me, and as I look back, is this lack of concrete examples and connection with the curves and surfaces which kept me from learning more. I liked this course on curves and surfaces: http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~shifrin/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf  If you like differential geometry, you'll like curves and surfaces.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You won't miss much by dropping curves and surfaces: every important article I studied, browsed or heard about  published in the last 60 years  in differential geometry by such luminaries as Thom, Milnor, Atiyah,  Hirzebruch, Perelman,...contains little or no reference to curves and surfaces.
On the other hand if you spend your time on Codazzi equations, Frenet-Serret frames and umbilic points you might have no time left for principal bundles, Stiefel-Whitney or Chern classes, cobordism,etc. and that means you will have little chance  of understanding anything in modern differential geometry.
Of course it would be great to combine  the mastery of both the exquisitely detailed classical results in one or two dimensions and the general powerful modern techniques of differential geometry/topology, but if you want to arrive at the frontier of research in a reasonable time you will have to favour the latter over the former.

Answer (score 4):

I agree that you'll be fine if you go straight into manifolds before curves and surfaces. But it is simply NOT true (as stated in another answer) that surface is of little interest in modern different geometry, in particular in area related to PDE and analysis.

In case of curves, that is indeed not so interesting as all 1 dimensional objects are locally isometric (So there are essentially no intrinsic properties to study). But there are still something extrinsic to talk about (for examples geodesic in Riemannian manifolds and closed orbit in symplectic manifolds). The studies are quite complete though (So really not so interesting from the research point of view).

But that is not the same for dimensional two. The main reason is that the most natural operator, the Laplace operator, is conformal invariant when dimensional is two. This results in a large contrast between surface theory and general manifold theory. Indeed, there has been large progress in minimal surface theory, mean curvature flow of surfaces, when compared to that in general dimension.

On the other hand, the use of surface theory is extremely essential in studying manifolds of positive curvatures, puesdo-holomorphic curves in symplectic manifolds etc, which are all active research directions in modern differential geometry.

Similar special phenomenon occurs when you restrict to 3 and 4 dimensional manifolds. These "low dimensional geometry" are also very active research directions.

However, I do agree that you can put aside the curve and surface theory for the moment. In a limit amount of time, it is reasonable to go into the general pictures first. I just feel like I have to say something for surface.

Comment: Agree. The theory of minimal surface in 3-manifolds has been understood relatively completely only in recent time (early 2000's) through a series of the works by Colding-Minicozzi. Personally I always like to use it as the primary example to remind myself to not 'look down' on the low-dimensional geometry, thinking that they are 'more or less trivial'. Another example would be the higher order (4th or above) parabolic PDEs (geometric flows) on curves in plane or space, which is still an active research area.